# Left recursion problem in Xtext "This rule call is part of a left recursive call graph."

Tags: java, xtext

I have written some Xtext code and tried to depict a Prologsyntax. Now I have a problem with left recursion and actually don't know what it is and how to solve my issue.

The line of NotEmptyList caused some errors.

```
PrologDsl: program=Program exquery=Exquery; 
Program: clause+=Clause+;
Exquery: '?-' query=Query '.';  
Query: predicate=Predicate (',' nthPredicate+=Predicate)*;
Clause: fact=Fact | rule=Rule;
Fact: predicate=Predicate '.';
Rule: predicate=Predicate ':-' query=Query '.';
Predicate: functor=Functor '(' term=Term (',' nthTerm+=Term)* ')';
Functor:IDENT;
Term:atom=Atom|list=List;
Atom: atom=(IDENT| VARIABLE | NUMBER);
List: emptyList = '[]' | list = NotEmptyList;
NotEmptyList: '[' folge=Folge ']' | '[' atom=Atom | term=Term ']';
Folge: atom=Atom (',' nthAtom+=Atom)* ;

terminal NUMBER:INT;
terminal VARIABLE: 'A'..'Z';
terminal IDENT: 'a'..'z'('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```

I belive that I have to include some new rules or can I simplify something?

Sorry I am a lousy beginner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

one problem is that a Folge and a NonEmptyList with a Atom are the same. so you can omit the latter.

```
List: emptyList = '[]' | list = NotEmptyList;
NotEmptyList: '[' (folge=Folge  | term=Term) ']';
```

similarly you have to help the parser here with Syntactic Predicates

```
Fact: =>(predicate=Predicate '.');
Rule: =>(predicate=Predicate ':-') query=Query '.';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have still two errors.
I tried this in the editor:

test([A|Z],Z,U):-test(Y,[B|Z],U).

This show me
-mismatched input '|' expecting ']' and
-mismatched input ':-' expecting '.'

Comment: sry cannot digg into that. you can generate a debug grammar and analyze from there using antlrworks v3

Comment: btw pipe ain't a keyword in your grammar. maybe thats the problem in the first place